# Bohr interpretation of Mach-Zehnder interferometer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, quantum-interpretations, interferometry

Consider MZI for single photon. Bohr or Copenhagen interpretation holds that the wave de Broglie attached to a particle is just amplitude(s) of probability (e.g. some information which is located (I suppose because of lack of knowledge) in the particle. So the particle 'knows' before it went through MZI what is the  configuration, are there two paths, what are the lengths, are there phase shifters PS etc. In fact everything. Even if one changes PS on the flight that info will reach the particle with speed c. How is this possible without a material carrier?

Comment: Let me know if my view on the Copenhagen is wrong not just put minuses. About lack of knowledge I mean that I have never read about that information and where it goes. I just suppose it gets in the particle. How the particle proceeds this info is another problem as it is regarded pointlike and structurless in QM.

Comment: This is in fact the central question in QM (Feynman), as MZI is fully equivalent to the DSE double slit experiment. In my opinion it is even more obvious.

Comment: It's not, see "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch, chapter 2.

Comment: If a particle can be in place A and place B, it also can be in superposition. You confuse superposition with a mixed state.

Comment: @alanf Can you give a very short explanation what is it?

Comment: @kludg What do you mean? I don't understand what A and B are there?

Answer (score 0):

No, a single particle having wave features or expressed as linear sum of its basis can't superimpose with itself or know priorly about its path. Reason is simple, if particles have their basis absolutely or dependent on situation, like in MZI it is two as beam splitter divides in two. What if instaed of double-slit, there are more slits then obviously its probability distribution changes. A photon is not in its various basis at a time just because it is not assigned with charge or mass, so no questiom of conservation of them.

A particle's basis have probability amplitude, in case of location they tell about probability of certain location as for statistics of any varaible. A wave is different and matter wave is different. If treating photon as particle, its behave as matter wave and locality become question. A dice rolled can be say as in all 6 number until it stops and reveal. It is way of description which hold for any similar non-quantum elements.

Comment: ‘No, a single particle having wave features or expressed as linear sum of its basis can't superimpose with itself or know priorly about its path.’
Do you know what happens in that experiment? Are you aware that every photon will lend (when an appropriately chosen difference in the paths is set) in only one of the channels?

Comment: @Mercury Is there any source which can produce one photon at a time. How is it detected by any instrument with such a sensitivity. This is similar to thought experiment in which bomb's liveness detected without detonating it. These interfeometer are based on division of amplitude, so they are good with intense light. Any probabilistic situation can be expressed as such, like a tossed coin in air can be described as both in head and tail, but this is description.

Comment: True single source since 1974: From Wikipedia:  Although the concept of a single photon was proposed by Planck as early as 1900,[1] a true single-photon source was not created in isolation until 1974. Single photon detectors from wiki: Many photodetectors can be configured to detect individual photons, each with relative advantages and disadvantages.[1][2] Common types include photomultipliers, geiger counters, single-photon avalanche diodes, superconducting nanowire single-photon detectors, transition edge sensors, and scintillation counters. Charge-coupled devices can be used.

Comment: https://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-36-10-1764
Stable single-photon interference in a 1 km fiber-optic Mach...  abstract
by GB Xavier · 2011 · Cited by 56 — We experimentally demonstrate stable and user-adjustable single-photon interference in a 1 km long fiber-optic Mach–Zehnder interferometer

Comment: A photon has locality of wavelength and it is described as superposition of all possible state. Then can it account for interference from multiple slits, like grating, where total length of grating is million times more than wavelength of photon

Answer (score 0):

Even before the photon is emitted its excited electron is already interacting with the EM field.  The EM field is very dynamic, the photon is the vehicle for the electrons to exchange energy.  The excited electron is exerting forces on many electrons ... even the electron that will eventually receive the photon .... these are called virtual forces.  The photon knows nothing ... the electrons and the EM field know it all!

Consider Feynman path integral ... every photon travels its own path, if the path is not ideal (per Feynman path integral) it is not travelled. Areas of non-travel are dark, all the photons go to the bright areas. The word 'interference" is out of date and historical and it violates conservation of energy! Photons never cancel, they are only emitted and eventually absorbed.

Comment: This is not Bohr interpretation! I also don’t know whose is this interpretation?

Comment: @Mercury, this is basic quantum field theory. A bunch of fundamental questions in quantum theory do in fact get simplified by looking at the field theoretical aspects.

Comment: @SongofPhysics I have studied QFT by Lewis Ryder from start to end (very much math but there is nothing said about problems of QM! Not a word about describing MZI by virtual particles! This should be very interesting how virtual partcles guide a real particle and make it to interfere with itself.

Comment: @Mercury  Bohr interpretation is from 1920, over 100 years ago.  If you want to understand MZI then use more modern concept from Richard Feynman, 1950s.  If you use Bohr for MZI it will give no satisfactory answer,  if you use Feynman and virtual fields (and particles .... although they are only for convenience) you will enjoy a good explanation and understanding of MZI.

Comment: @Mercury  What does Lewis Ryder state about MZI?  .... does he use Bohr principle?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Where is the material about this? I can not study it on myself. Please cite a book where MZI or DSE are explained based on virtual particles! This interpretation is closes to Bohm's one. There are strong objections against Bohm because it is a hidden variable theory. Throwing Bohr interpretation in the basket is more than revolution. And yes it is 100 years old now.

Comment: Ryder says nothing on MZI. He calculates amplitudes. Bohr principle is self understood. He uses virtual particles of course in the Feynman diagrammes and in the Lamb shift. But Lamb shift is far from MZI.

Comment: https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=ekyAV8VtfuYC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&ots=MYEl2CknSV&sig=smMc4NsST53aFFdb1TpBh109gwQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=virtual&f=false

Comment: @Mercury above is link to a Bohr-Slater paper.  Note the Slater interpretation of fields and atomic interactions.  This paper is old a well.  In general virtual fields are concepts but the forces are real ... hence there are not a lot of papers on virtual photons.

Comment: @Mercury https://www.academia.edu/4401552/On_the_Physical_Reality_of_Quantum_Waves  This a another discussion of fields/waves and it includes MZI.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Ok I take a look. I hope this will do better than Copenhagen which i dont loke and even less understand (in my mind nobody understands his view). But Copenhagen was/is predominant in QM for 100 years. No one dared to criticise them except Bohm who was put in the corner. How is i there is a better interpretation  and it stays so obscured even in contemporary QM books.

Comment: @PhysicsDave I dont think Feynman approach is any different than Bohr. The particles follows all trajectories/paths without being anywhere is just a reformilation in other math tools of the same vanishing of the particle in Bohr.

Comment: In fact I wanted to get a look at the view or Copenhagenists on MZI. Is there a particle? Where is the particle at the start? How does it move in the two arms? How it appears in one arm if observed? How is decided by whom? that it goes left in the splitter when the other path has difference lambda?

Comment: @Mercury you are indeed correct in the sense that the path integral doesn't exactly provide a "different" interpretation. As far as criticisms go against Copenhagen, they exist and there is work going on in other so-called interpretations. This is however, not related to your original question.

Comment: Furthermore @Mercury, to add to your grievance about your QFT reference not dealing with foundational problems in quantum theory, I say that it is not its purpose to.

Comment: @SongofPhysics Is this QFT interpretation not in fact a hidden variable theory (actually a Bohm variant for ontological WF) which are theoretically ruled out?